# Iterating through form-data with nested keys in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a project using Django Rest Framework, where I need to create a company by sending relevant documents through form-data. When I print the data received, it looks like this:

```
{
    'company[company_owner][email]': ['rohansheryabraham@gmail.com'],
    'company[company_owner][phone]': ['098765439'],
    'company[company_owner][first_name]': ['Mike'],
    'company[company_owner][last_name]': ['Tyson'],
    'company[company_name]': ['Testing'],
    'company[company_email]': ['testing@mail.com'],
    'company[company_mobile_phone]': ['980765432'],
    'company[company_landline]': ['78765421'],
    'company[company_country]': ['India'],
    'company[email_otp]': ['783143'],
    'company[mobile_otp]': ['256310'],
    'company_detail[0][detail]': ['110'],
    'company_details[0][documents]': [
        '<InMemoryUploadedFile: Screenshot from 2023-11-27 11-50-29.png (image/png)>','<InMemoryUploadedFile: Screenshot from 2023-11-27 11-50-20.png (image/png)>'
    ]
}
```

Now unlike JSON I cannot dynamically access documents in form-data like
`print(company_detail[0]['documents'])` can anyone suggest a good way to iterate this?

For now, I am just printing data.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@parser_classes([FormParser, MultiPartParser])
def test(request):
    print(request.data)
    #logic to create company

    return Response()
```

Comment: please can you add any example against documents key. so we understand what kind of possible list we get

Comment: @TanveerAhmad. added 2 docs. for some reason when I send docs all key values become a list

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** **company_details[0][documents]** key must be present in json

```
for k, v in test.items():
    if k == 'company_details[0][documents]':
        for i in v:
            print(i)
            # remaining code here
```